# React native stack navigation goBack() not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I created common header for all pages, so create header component then i include that header in signup.js component goback navigation function working in signup.js page but not working header component getting undefined object navigate.goback error

Anyone give a solution for that like that i include component

sample code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, TextInput,KeyboardAvoidingView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import {Icon,Body,Button,Title,Left,Right} from 'native-base';
import Expo from "expo";
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import Headerbar from "./../Header/header";
import Statusbar from "./../statusbar";
const googleIcon=require('../../../img/google_icon.png');
const fbIcon=require('../../../img/fb_icon.png');
export default class Socialsignup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    };
   
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.socialContainer}  scrollEnabled={true}> 
        <Statusbar/>
        <Headerbar title="Social Login"   />
          <View style={styles.socialText}>
                  <Text style={styles.accountText}>Choose an account</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.socialIconsBase}>
                <View style={styles.socialIconsGoogle}>
                    <Image source={googleIcon} style={styles.googleIcon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>
                      Google
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.socialIconsGoogle}>
                <Image source={fbIcon} style={styles.fbIcon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>
                      Facebook
                    </Text>
                </View>
          </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  socialContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  accountText: {
      marginTop:25,
      fontSize:20,
      padding:20
  },
  socialIconsBase:
  {
    flexDirection:'row',
    flex:1,
    marginTop:40,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor:'#a8c0ce'
  },
  socialIconsGoogle:
  {
      flex:1,
      alignItems:'center',
      paddingTop:25,
      paddingBottom:25,
      borderRightWidth:1,
      borderRightColor:'#a8c0ce',
      marginBottom:8,
  },
  fbIcon:{
    height:50,
    width:50,
  },
  googleIcon:{
    height:50,
    width:50,
  },
  iconText:{
        fontSize:15,
        marginTop:15
  }
  
});
```

Comment: aside note: you may need to check this link: https://reactnatve.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/alias-in-react-native/

Comment: @challenger may i know how to pass navigation properties to import page ??

Comment: check this answer below

Comment: Thanks for your help, But if i use like that i am getting  you should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router> error

Comment: ah oki... did you add the <Router> wrapper ?

Comment: Another one doubt which is best for react native app expo or xcode or android studio??

Comment: I prefer atom :p

Comment: I was an android developer, I tried expo and android studio... atom with the proper and good plugins, is the best ever..

Comment: but xcode and android studio are editors!! any way...  I don't like expo,, the react native cli and not expo... check this https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/339

Comment: Expo means easy to view the changes but now i run react-native run-android take more time in emulator and windows not able run ios command right, we need to work on mac for both right??

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this inside the header component :

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
```

and then instead of `export default HeaderClassName`

use `export default withRouter(HeaderClassName)`

and you can go back by `this.props.history.goBack()`

You need to use this too:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
```

and then add the pages like that

```
<Route path='/page' component={Page} />
```

Comment: Thanks @challenger if i use like this na i am getting you should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>